# Publication list in Ph.D. thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, thesis, front-matter

I am writing my Ph.D. thesis and I would like to add a list of the publications my thesis is based on. I would like the list to be in the first pages of the thesis, so I put it at the end of the `\frontmatter`. Now my `\frontmatter` is composed as follows

- Title page
- Dedication
- Abstract (two languages as required by my Institution)
- Table of contents
- List of figures
- List of publications

First question: I know that it is a matter of personal taste, but is it this order for the front matter unusual? What would be a more usual order?

Second question: being in the `\frontmatter` the list of publications has a roman numeration, and appears in the table of contents as follows:

[image: Table of content, snippet.]

Is it weird that roman numbers appear in the table of contents? Would it be better to put the list in the `\mainmatter`? Or is it better for `\mainmatter` to start with actual content, which is the Introduction chapter?

Answer (score 2):

(I think this question is off-topic here, but I'm not sure.)

You should either include all of **ToC**, **LoF** and **List of Publications** in the table of contents, or none of them. And (with my copy editor hat one) this order makes sense to me.

Another option is to make the list of publications an unnumbered section in the Introduction, but one that is included in ToC; that's what I did for my thesis.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I hope my question is not off-topic, actually you may be right, it's more about style than LaTeX.